# How can I compile with LLVM/Clang to RISC-V target?

Tags: compilation, clang, llvm, riscv

I want to compile a simple program "int main(){return 0;}" to RISC-V processor.
LLVM/Clang version is 9.0 and I want to run the compiled program with a RISC-V simulator like this https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools

My problem is that I can't list the clang supported targets only the LLC-s whith these commands:

```
llc --version
llc -march=xxARCHTYPExx -mattr=help
```

And there is no any type of riscv processor listed.

So I tried to look the triple file: `llvm-project\llvm\include\llvm\ADT\Triple.h`

and try a command like: `clang hello.c -target riscv32 -march=rv32imafd`

But I get the following error:

> error: unable to create target: 'No available targets are compatible
>   with triple "riscv32"'

Can somebody help me to how get a valid RISC-V target? I just simple can't compile the program but I know LLVM has a RISC-V support.

Comment: The LLVM source code has RISC-V support, but that doesn't mean that your compiled version has that target enabled. `cmake -DDLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=all .` gives you a version of LLVM that supports all targets.

Comment: I tried this command and get the following error when CMake is finished:

CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD

According to this webpage the default is "all" if I don't specify the target:
https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html

Comment: The problem was with -DDLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=all 
The correct is -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=all
But the original problem is still on.

Comment: I'm able to build with these options:
cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld" -DLLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="RISCV" -DLLVM_USE_LINKER=gold -DBENCHMARK_DOWNLOAD_DEPENDENCIES=ON ../llvm

But when I want to create a runnable program:
clang hello.c --target=riscv64 -march=rv64i -c -o hello.o
ld.lld hello.o -o hello

It will create a runnable but it seems the instruction are missing inside the file. So it will not work.

Comment: Maybe I found the answer in here: https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html


 "The document focuses on existing examples found in subdirectories of llvm/lib/Target in a downloaded LLVM release. In particular, this document focuses on the example of creating a static compiler (one that emits text assembly) for a SPARC target, because SPARC has fairly standard characteristics, such as a RISC instruction set and straightforward calling conventions."

So it will only generate an assembly not a runnable...

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68580399/using-clang-to-compile-for-risc-v

Answer (score 8):

LLVM 9 [release notes](https://riscv.org/2019/09/llvm-9-releases-with-official-risc-v-target-support-asm-goto-clang-9-and-more-vincy-davis-packt-pub/) explicitly state that RISC-V support was promoted from experimental to official.

And indeed, on my Fedora 31 machine, the LLVM 9 Fedora package does support RISC-V:

```
$ llvm-objdump --version | grep riscv
    riscv32    - 32-bit RISC-V
    riscv64    - 64-bit RISC-V
```

Also, I can create RISC-V binary code with the LLVM toolchain:

```
$ clang --target=riscv64 -march=rv64gc rotate.s -c -o rotate.o
$ file rotate.o
rotate.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, UCB RISC-V, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Although it doesn't include a libc for RISC-V targets:

```
$ clang --target=riscv64 -march=rv64gc hello-world.c -o hello-world
hello-world.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

However, you don't really need one - you could directly call syscalls for your hello world, e.g.:

```
$ clang  --target=riscv64 -march=rv64gc  hello.s -c -o hello.o
$ ld.lld hello.o -o hello
$ spike --isa=RV64gc ~/local/riscv/pk/riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/pk ./hello
bbl loader
Hello World
```

I don't use clang for linking because it seems that I can't convince clang with `-fuse-ld` to use another linker besides `/usr/bin/ld`.

Comment: The `-fuse-ld` issue is caused by an upstream bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1803698

Comment: In your examples above, how did you generate rotate.s and hello.s?

Comment: @erwaman - I wrote them  - [rotate.s](https://github.com/gsauthof/riscv/blob/master/rotate.s) is available in my riscv github repository.

Comment: Also added [hello.s](https://github.com/gsauthof/riscv/blob/master/hello.s) now.